# Allow custom bundle to add it's own config setting for another bundle (Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a custom Bundle, let's call it `FooBarBundle`.

Now, from within a custom Extension, I would like to prepend the following:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            FooBarBundle : ~
```

I'm under the belief that this shouldn't be possible, but I can't find any confirmation that one bundle cannot prepend configuration options of another Bundle.

I'm not sure if this is related: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html

Ideally, I would like a bunch of my own bundles to add their own Doctrine Mappings rather than rely on updating the Config.yml when using each Bundle.

Comment: The Symfony config component allows you to define config files in multiple places so it might be possible.  It depends in part on how the doctrine extension is written.  I'd be tempted to put some debug statements in vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle and see what happens.  Little bit skeptical about the value of doing this but be interested in seeing if it works,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this for each bundle without to update the `config.yml` file:

```
namespace FooBarBundle\DependencyInjection;

// ...

class FooBarExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    //...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->loadFromExtension('doctrine', array(
            'orm' => array(
                'mappings' => array(
                     'FooBarBundle' => null,
                )
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

If you have many bundles each config will be merged.